# Make two vectors of different lengths equal in length

Tags: r

I have two vectors of different lenghts. How can I start both series so their ends concide.

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6)
y<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4)
```

I do it with the code below but I guess there must be a more elegant way

```
x<-x[((length(x)-length(y))+1):length(x)]

x
 [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6
y
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4
```

Comment: Try `tail (y, length (x))`

Comment: Thanks, how would you go on determining which of x or y is the longest vector from the initial series

Comment: That's another question but you can divide the length of each x/y if the answer it >1 then x is longer if 1 they are equal if <1 y is longer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `tail`, and `min` to determine the shortest vector:

```
shortest <- min(length(x), length(y))
y <- tail(y, shortest)
x <- tail(x, shortest)
```