# Conditionally removing a vector element

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have two vectors a, b where b can be 1 unit longer than a. In such case I need to remove the last element of vector b to make them equal. I tried following:

```
a <- c(1:3)
b <- c(1:4)

b <- ifelse(length(a) != length(b), b[-length(b)], b)
b <- ifelse(length(a) != length(b), b[-NROW(b)], b)
```

In both case, I get

```
> b
[1] 1
```

But when I do this out of ifelse() then I can get what I expect:

```
c <- c(1:4)
c <- c[-length(c)]

> c
[1] 1 2 3
```

I know how to write this using "if", but I am looking for a better option.

Comment: Posibble dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217849/make-two-vectors-of-different-lengths-equal-in-length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifelse` is for vectorized conditions, here you are checking a scalar condition so you should use `if` (if you have to).

However, in this case you don't need both. You can iterate over the index of `a` which will give correct length of `b` irrespective if it is longer or of same length.

```
b[seq_along(a)]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 3):

I would just subset the vector using the first vector's length as the upper bound:

```
a <- c(1:3)
b <- c(1:4)
b[1:length(a)]

[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: How would you know though which vector is the smallest? Maybe it's better to generalise it a bit more...

Comment: `I have two vectors a, b where b can be 1 unit longer than a` ... I answered based on the assumptions given in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

```
length(b) <- length(a)
b
[1] 1 2 3
```